How does the homing work on Creality K1 Max?
After playing with shims I was able to reach a good tradeoff with bed leveling:

I rotated the image to better show what I mean: the right side of the picture is the back of the printer, where there is the single Z screw.
In other words, the shims allowed me to compensate the left-right inclination. Now I have "only" to compensate the front-back inclination.
Of course I can add other 2x 0.5 mm shims on the front Z-screws, but I tried a smarter solution: I disabled the motors and carefully CCW rotated the back Z-screw so only the rear part of the bed lowered by a fraction of a mm.
Then I did again the bed leveling procedure. But the returned mesh is exactly the same.
I'm afraid the homing procedure has three independent endstop sensors, that would prevent my not-so-smart tentative to work.
Can anybody confirm that?
Must I rely on shims again or is there a simpler way to lower the back Z-screw only of about 0.5 mm?
